# post JSON from HttpClient to web API in C#

Tags: c#, rest

I'm trying to POST a JASON data from HttpClient to my REST API,but it's not working.
the client and the Rest API are not in the same project/solution.

on the HttpClient i'm using the following code:

```
 private static async void DoIt()
    {
        string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            agent = new
            {
                Id = 3,
                Text = "Test item3",
            },

           
        });

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44323/api/listid", content);


    }
```

the model on the REST API:

```
public class CustomListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

}
```

the POST method on REST API:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] CustomListItem model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model?.Text))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var maxId = 0;
        if (_listItems.Count > 0)
        {
            maxId = _listItems.Max(x => x.Id);
        }
        model.Id = maxId + 1;
        _listItems.Add(model);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, model);
    }
```

can you please help?

Comment: In your serialized object you are nesting `CustomListItem` as a property `agent` so your model in the REST is not in the right shape.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hamlet, I'm not sure i know how to fix it, can you please show me on the code?

Comment: "but it's not working" Could you pls explain what does it mean? what error do you have?

Answer (score 0):

What Hamlet is referring to is that you are generating JSON like this:

```
{
    agent: {
        Id: 3,
        Text: "Test item3"
    }
}
```

But your API is expecting just this:

```
{
    Id: 3,
    Text: "Test item3"
}
```

So you need to change your code to:

```
string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        Id = 3,
        Text = "Test item3",
    };
```

Comment: Hello my friends, i have changed the payload but i still dont get result, when i post value using postman everything works on the web API side

Comment: @ShayAvitapl could you edit your question to show the current state of your code?